# Alamofire requests with response type of text/html

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, httpresponse

I am converting an Objective C project into swift and as a result, I need to use Alamofire instead of AFNetworking. The server I need to make HTTP calls to expects parameters in JSON format but responds in text/html. When I test the requests in Objc, it works but on swift and alamofire, the response data is nil. I have done this previously using AFNetworking responseSerializer and set the acceptable content types to all 4 possible types. I just can't seem to make this work with Alamofire. I have used any help and tutorials out there but I am banging my head to the ceiling each time. Te errors I get are usually Unable to determine byte size or responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength.

Here is sample code I have used so far:

```
let urlString = "\(K.APIKs.kInsecureProtocol)\(K.APIKs.KBaseURL)\(K.APIKs.kSignupURL)"
        let parameters: Parameters = [K.SignUPKs.kMSISDN: number]

        AF.request(urlString, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                self.authorisingSignUpDelegate?.onAuthorisingSignUpSuccess()
                break

            case .failure(let error):
                self.authorisingSignUpDelegate?.onAuthorisingSignUpFailed(error: error)
                break

            }
        }
```

then tried setting the acceptable content types:

```
if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
            urlRequest.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
            urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
            urlRequest.addValue("text/html", forHTTPHeaderField: "accept")
            urlRequest.httpBody =  try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)

            let request = AF.request(urlRequest)
                .response { response  in
                print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")  // original URL request
                print("---------------------------")
                print("HTTP URL response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // HTTP URL response
                print("---------------------------")
                print("Data: \(String(describing: response.data))")     // server data
                print("---------------------------")
                print("Result of Reponse Serialization \(response.result)")   // result of response serialization
                print("---------------------------")
                print("Error \(response.error)")   // result of response serialization
                print("---------------------------")

                print("JSON: \(response.result)")
                }
}
```

None of the methods I have tried work. Can anyone help me please? Thanks a million!

Comment: You can use `debugPrint(response)` to see more detailed content in the response and see if you truly have no data. Otherwise it seems like an issue with the request you're sending, so you need to investigate any differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who'd have a similar problem, I wrote the fix as follow:

```
if let returnedData = JSONData {
                    do {
                        let dict =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: returnedData, options: []) as? [String: String]
                        DataManager().synchronisePassword(from: dict!)

                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
```